# Unable to set a javascript date object to a cell hidden by filter

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I have a script which checks certain conditions to send reminders emails or sms to my clients. the only issues I'm finding is that if I try to write a cell that is hidden by a filter, the script executes but the data is not changed in any way.

I'll write a short version of the whole script:

```
function test(){
    var nowTime = new Date();  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var lastrow =sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastcol =sheet.getLastColumn();
    var fullData =cell.offset(0, 0,lastrow- 
    cell.getRow()+1,lastcol).getValues();
    var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
    var i=0;
    while (i<fullData.length){
        var reminderType =0;
        var row = fullData[i];
        if (row[0] == 1) {sendreminder();cell.offset(i, 2).setValue(new Date());}
    }
}
```

if for example the first column has hidden all the rows with 1 the script executes and sends all the reminders but ignore the setvalue(), if the rows are visible it works perfectly.

One solution can de to remove the filter but would be very annoying since we use the filter a lot and the script is triggered by time every 10 minutes so I would be working on the sheet and suddenly the filter get removed to run the script.

I have tried with cell.offset, getrange etc.. without any success ... Ideas?

**EDIT:** The problem seems to be only if I try to write a date `if (row[0] == 1) {cell.offset(i, 1).setValue(new Date());}`
For instance I'm writing another information (a number) in a different column and that cell gets updated.

The rest remain the same
here is a test sheet I created:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FNDGmvCc8nRFTG65Sj9L2RhGn8R3DtwR3llwBG5-FA/edit#gid=0

Comment: @TheMaster, same result :( Maybe one solution might be to have the all column in an array and use setValues to set all the values of the column, I didn't try yet but I really don't like to use this solution because someone might be editing the sheet an it increase the probabilities of conflict, also might become more process intense since I have to store and write a full column maybe to update 1 value.

Comment: @TheMaster you are right the script I created for the sample works, I did an update, the problems looks like to appear only when trying to write a date in the cell.

Comment: Consider starring this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68916111 and related issues.

Comment: @TheMaster I will thank you! Does not look like it will be solved soon since its an issue since 2017 :(

Answer (score 0):

For now I added this code to save the state of the filter and reestablish it at the end. It's not really elegant and still add a lot of chances of something being messed up or the script failing but it's the less invasive solution I came out with. Does someone has a better one?

```
// at the beginning
if (sheet1.getFilter()){
     var filterRange= sheet1.getFilter().getRange();
     var filterSetting = [];
var i=0;
 while (i<filterRange.getNumColumns()-1) {filterSetting[i]= sheet1.getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(i+1);sheet1.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(i+1);i++; }
}
// At the end
 if (sheet1.getFilter()){
 var i=0;
 while (i<filterRange.getNumColumns()-1) {if (filterSetting[i]) sheet1.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(i+1, filterSetting[i]);i++; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact the problem is not writing in the hidden row as it was pointed out, the solution is to use the formatdate to format the value before writing it in the cell.

Not ideal either since regional formattings might prevent the script from working on different accounts but sure better solution than disabling the filters.

here is the code i needed to add:

```
var nowTime = new Date();  
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
var nowTimeFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(nowTime, timeZone, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

any idea on how to improve this script or to solve the original problem without workarounds is appreciated :)